# Is there any concept behind passing a scala immutable Map to a map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Line no 2 "pws" Map is being passed to the map method how come it is replacing the values for that key? can anyone explain how it is working internally?

```
scala> val pws = Map("Apache Spark" -> "http://spark.apache.org/", "Scala" -> "http://www.scala-lang.org/")
pws: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Apache Spark -> http://spark.apache.org/, Scala -> http://www.scala-lang.org/)

scala> val websites = sc.parallelize(Seq("Apache Spark", "Scala")).map(pws).collect
...
websites: Array[String] = Array(http://spark.apache.org/, http://www.scala-lang.org/)

/*
for better understanding*/

scala> val websites = sc.parallelize(Seq("Apache Spark", "Scala"))
websites: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[6] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> websites.first()
res10: String = Apache Spark

scala> pws

res11: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Apache Spark -> http://spark.apache.org/, Scala -> http://www.scala-lang.org/)

scala> val websites = sc.parallelize(Seq("Apache Spark", "Scala")).map(pws)
websites: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[8] at map at <console>:26

scala> websites.first()

res12: String = http://spark.apache.org/
```

[How come the "Apache Spark"(first value) got replaced to "http://spark.apache.org/"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any concept behind passing a scala immutable Map to a map function

The concept is called "subtyping":

1. [`scala.collection.immutable.Map[K, +V]` extends `scala.collection.immutable.MapOps[K, V, scala.collection.immutable.Map, scala.collection.immutable.Map[K, V]]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html)
2. [`scala.collection.immutable.MapOps[K, +V, +CC[X, +Y] <: MapOps[X, Y, CC, _], +C <: MapOps[K, V, CC, C]]` (where `CC` = `scala.collection.immutable.Map` and `C` = `scala.collection.immutable.Map[K, V]`) extends `scala.collection.MapOps[K, V, CC, C
   ]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/MapOps.html)
3. [`scala.collection.MapOps[K, +V, +CC[_, _] <: IterableOps[_, collection.AnyConstr, _], +C]` (where `CC` = `scala.collection.immutable.Map` and `C` = `scala.collection.immutable.Map[K, V]`) extends `scala.PartialFunction[K, V]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/MapOps.html)
4. [`scala.PartialFunction[-A, +B]` (where `A` = `K` and `B` = `V`) extends `(A) ⇒ B` (which is syntactic sugar for `scala.Function1[A, B]`)](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html)

So, in other words: `Map[K, +V]`s *are* [`Function1[K, +V]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html)s, therefore you can pass a `Map` to a method expecting a `Function1` as an argument. [`scala.collection.immutable.Seq[+A].map[B]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html#map[B](f:A=>B):CC[B]) expects an argument of type `(A) ⇒ B`, and a `Map` *is* (a subtype of) that type. And since I can pass an instance of a subtype anywhere I can pass an instance of the supertype without changing the meaning of the program (that's what the [*Liskov Substitution Principle*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) guarantees us), that is well-typed and valid.

Think about it: what is a function? [A function is a mapping from inputs to outputs](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)). You give the function an input argument, the function gives you the output as a return value.

What is a map? It is a mapping from keys to values. You give the map a key argument, the map gives you the value as a return value.

They are very much *the same thing*.

Similar reasoning applies to `Seq`s: a sequence is a mapping of natural numbers to elements. And for `Set`s: a set is a mapping from elements to booleans.